# Firestore function - update newly created data with cloud script before returning result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a document locally, upload it to Firestore, let the server code run and get the result from this. How can I do that?

My example is working fine, but the result of my `startNewGame` function does not wait for the server script to finish and returns old data (the server script did not yet update the document). After refreshing the data, my app retrieves the correct data (modified by the server script).

Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

My `startNewGame` function also uploads the game, this means, the final result should be the modified version from the server, shouldn't it?

**Code**

```
fun startNewGame(): Single<GameModel> {
    var model = GameModel(UserManager.user!!.uid, null)
    // 1) create game
    var res: Single<DocumentReference> = Single.create({ emitter ->
        MainApp.db.collection(Constants.FIREBASE_GAME).add(model)
                .addOnCompleteListener({ task ->
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            emitter.onSuccess(task.result)
                        } else {
                            emitter.onError(Throwable(task.getException()))
                        }
                    }
                })
    })
    // 2) upload game
    res = res.flatMap { game -> uploadGame(game) }
    return res
}

private fun uploadGame(game: GameModel): Single<GameModel> {
    return Single.create<GameModel>({ emitter ->
        game.doc!!.set(game).addOnCompleteListener({ task ->
            if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    emitter.onSuccess(game)
                } else {
                    emitter.onError(Throwable(task.getException()))
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**Simple test server script:**

```
exports.findGame = functions.firestore
    .document('/games/{gameId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        const newData = event.data.data();
        var user1 = newData.player1

        console.log('New game created by user ' + newData.player1 + '!');

        // returning the promise should have the result, that we wait for the function
        return event.data.ref.set({
            player2: 'SOME PLAYER 2'
        }, {merge: true}).then(res => {
              console.log('Player 2 set');
              return res;
            })
});
```

Comment: You have to query to get modified version of data. Once your client adds   data to firestore and then that triggers your cloud function to update the same data right.

Comment: Currently firestore is in beta and docs say, that there may be a delay of seconds between the cloud function and the create event. This would mean I would have to query the modified data and check if modification has finished and if not, query it again? Is there no better way? I want to wait until the function is finished... I could alternatively push the result back to the device, but that seems like making this simple task overly complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `addOnCompleteListener` try `addSnapshotListener`.  When the data is updated, your app should automatically get the update.